# inner join on two columns of same table on another table including with OR condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 - `USERS`:

```
user_id | email_id         | type
---------------------------------------
000121  | test_20@test.com | EXT
000125  | best_21@test.com | LOT
000128  | lite_21@test.com | EXT
```

Table 2- `HISTORY`:

```
old_user_id | new_user_id | another_type
----------------------------------------
000128      | 000121      | INIT
```

I have `email_id` in hand say `test_20@test.com`, I want to do a join query that should return 1, if the `user_email_id` I had, is in `USERS` table with `EXT` as TYPE and in `HISTORY` table with `ANOTHER_TYPE` as `INIT`;

I have a query with a single join for `old_user_id` .

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   history cmr (nolock) 
                  INNER JOIN users au (nolock) 
                          ON au.user_id = cmr.old_user_id 
                  AND cmr.another_type = 'INIT  'AND au.type = 'EXT' 
                   AND au.email_id = 'test_20@test.com') 
  SELECT 1 ELSE   SELECT 0
```

When I query `test_20@test.com` or `test_20@test.com`, it should return 1. I want to add the join condition for `new_user_id` also .

So either user (old or new) should be `EXT` in `USERS`, and should be `INIT` in `HISTORY`

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about adding "or" to join condition like (au.user_id = cmr.old_user_id or au.user_id = cmr.new_user_id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM   history cmr 
Left JOIN users au  ON au.user_id = cmr.old_user_id  AND cmr.another_type = 'INIT  'AND au.type = 'EXT'  AND au.email_id = 'test_20@test.com' 
Left JOIN users au2  ON au2.user_id = cmr.new_user_id  AND cmr.another_type = 'INIT  'AND au2.type = 'EXT'  AND au2.email_id = 'test_20@test.com'
Where (au.user_id is NOT NULL) or (au2.user_id is NOT NULL)
)
SELECT 1 ELSE   SELECT 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `case when`: **BTW `user` is a reserved keyword. So you may want to use square brackets with 
it.**

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0012/10)

Query 1:

```
SELECT case when 
       EXISTS (Select * From historyT cmr 
       Left Join userT au  
       On (au.user_id = cmr.old_user_id  
       And cmr.another_type = 'INIT'
       And au.type = 'EXT'  
       And au.email_id = 'test_20@test.com')) 
       Then 1
       Else 0
End  Status               
;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT case when 
   EXISTS (Select * From historyT cmr 
   Left Join userT au  
   On (au.user_id = cmr.old_user_id  
   And cmr.another_type = 'INIT'
   And au.type = 'EXT'  
   And au.email_id = 'test_20@test.com') 
   Left Join userT au2  
   On (au2.user_id = cmr.new_user_id  
   And cmr.another_type = 'INIT' 
   And au2.type = 'EXT'  
   And au2.email_id = 'test_20@test.com'
   And (au.user_id is Not Null) 
   or (au2.user_id is Not Null)))
   Then 1
   Else 0
```

End  Status
;

Results:

```
STATUS
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM 
                history cmr (nolock) INNER JOIN 
                users au (nolock) 
           ON 
                (au.user_id = cmr.old_user_id or au.user_id = cmr.new_user_id)
           WHERE 
                  cmr.another_type = 'INIT' AND 
                  au.type = 'EXT' AND 
                  au.email_id = 'test_20@test.com') 
  SELECT 1 
ELSE   
  SELECT 0
```